# how to get the days of 2,3,4 months in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the days of more then 1 month if pass 2 , 3 ,4 as number of month to the function, I want to get total number of days from today

```
function get_days_in_month(months){
   days_in_month = new Date();
   var y = days_in_month.getFullYear();
   var m = days_in_month.getMonth();
   if(months==1){
      return new Date(y,m+1,0).getDate();
   }
  if(months==2){
    // need to write code or some other logic
  } 
}
```

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
var total = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= months; i++) {
    total += new Date(y, m + i, 0).getDate();
}

return total;
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LyYGe/).

Comment: This wrong If i pass 1 it return 1 if i pass 2 it return 3 if pass 3 it return 6
        var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);

Comment: @SohailYasmin Looks like I accidentally put a comma instead of a plus (`m, i` instead of `m + i`). I've fixed the answer now and added a JSFiddle demo.